# Typescript: inferred type of expression with && or ||

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Look at [this program in TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=27&pln=7&pc=36#code/FAYwNghgzlAECCsDewC%20wBmBXAdiALgJYD2OsGAFAB4BcARscWAKYQ4CUywsPsL%20sCAF4czAO4IK7ANzdeAenmwAXjQwQwUZrAA%20COT34qAjEKqwAZBcHTYikzXIatu-bz7MBygExndeiFt7H0dEXgpYHGIBACJ8ACcsbT14GPYDWBBSKCZmADowYgBzCmVjABofGXc0TAoEpJl7BBokVFhy2AbmOvVNZialPq1O%20Ec24CA):

```
class A {
}
function f(x:boolean) {
    let a=new A();
    let z1=x && a; // z1: false | A
    let z2=x || a; // z2: A    ( not "true | A")
    console.log(z1,z2);    
}
f(true);//  A:{} , true
f(false);// false, A: {}
```

I checked inferred types of z1 and z2 by hovering the mouse cursor on z1 and z2.
Then,

- z1 is inferred as `false|A`
- z2 is inferred as `A`

I guessed that z2 would be inferred as `true|A`. Is it just a bug of TS compiler (or playground) or correct behavior defined by specification?

Comment: I looked into your example, and find it very curious. I reduced it to the following repro  https://tsplay.dev/wezZVN have you considered reporting it at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues I'm sure it's a known feature (since it's so easy to reproduce) but I'm unsure how or why it could be deliberate.

Comment: I raised it at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54168

Comment: [Empty classes behave strangely](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) and are best avoided, even for example code.  Right now the `A` type is equivalent to `{}` and accepts almost any value except `null` or `undefined`; the types `A`, `true | A`, and `false | A` are equivalent.  Not sure why the compiler collapses one but not the other, but in some sense this is an implementation detail. What use case did this come from and do you really expect to have a class with no members?  Trying to figure out how to triage this question.

Comment: Thanks for answering and reporting. I checked the behavior when A has some members: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAECCsDexZtgSwLwGYDcwAvsAGYCuAdiAC4YD2FsJAFAB4BcARnXWAKYQKASmSp0-arAhYKfAO4JmQgulgB6NbABe7EhDBQ+sAD4IxaCdoCMWVrABk9qXnWatV9k32GTZ1Za0AJlsTUwgXDW1Az2oAJzIjU0RYABpYTjJJDBIEWAALaFgKOlgAWz5Szj5YtL90EAYoXj4AOjA6AHNmdxSg5VUiUmY4hOVIhHYkQlTYEb4hvQM+Mc1FwzT4TyngIA

Comment: Okay so when you add members, the problem disappears.  Does that mean that this is a non-issue and we should close the question?  Or do you have some reason for using an empty class (and if so, what is that reason)?  I could write up an answer here saying "this is working as intended" and explaining why, but I don't know if that actually has any benefit to anyone, since I don't understand the use case.  Could you clarify?